# Handling missing values using dateutil.parser in python

Tags: python, date, parsing

I'm using python dateutil to standardize  date formats,the ideal case is that I have all the date:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
date1 = '2012/01/02'
parse(date1)
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

But that's not the case for all the records, there are 2 cases I want to handle:

first, invalid values:

```
date2 = '2012/19/01'
parse(date2)
ValueError: month must be in 1..12

date2 = '2012/1/00'
parse(date2)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

For those cases I still want to have whichever data is available, for the first example the year, and for the second on both year and month.

Second Case, missing values:

```
date3 = '/1/10'
parse(date3)
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 10, 0, 0)
```

If date, month or year are not available I don't want to get the current year, month or day without getting notice, I need to use a default value for those cases.

Comment: ?
what is `parse` here? can you please parse function definition

Comment: @saikumarm from dateutil.parser import parse

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should write a parser method,which check out the input string and replace illegal date with default value:

```
from datetime import datetime
default=['2017','1','1']

def paretime(t):
    i=t.split('/')
    if len(i)<3:
        return None
    y,m,d = i
    if y not in range(1,2018):
        y=default[0]
    if m not in range(1, 13):
        m=default[1]
    if d not in range(1, 32):
        d=default[2]
    return datetime.strptime("-".join([y,m,d]), '%Y-%m-%d')


print paretime('/1/1')
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

Or

```
default=['2017','1','1']
from datetime import datetime

def paretime(t):
    d={i:j for i,j in enumerate(t.split('/')) if i==0 and j in (1,2018) if i==1 and j in (1,13)  if i==2 and j in (1,32)}
    return datetime.strptime("-".join([d.get(0,default[0]),d.get(1,default[1]),d.get(2,default[2])]), '%Y-%m-%d')

print paretime('/41/0')
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

Hope this helps.